# Finding all the intervals that does not overlap with the point

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have intervals of the form `(a1, b1), (a2, b2), ...., (an, bn)`.
I would like to support the following operations

1. Adding a new interval.
2. Deleting an existing interval.
3. Given a point, find all intervals that do not overlap with the point.

Intervals tree is the straightforward solution if we want to find intervals which overlap with the point. What about the case when we want to find non intersecting intervals?

Comment: What do "add" and "delete" exactly mean? Should adding `(2,4)` to `(1,3)` produce `(1,3),(2,4)` or `(1,4)`?

Comment: @Oriol -  think it should be `(1,3),(2,4)`

Comment: You can insert in the tree the complementaries of the intervals: instead of [a,b], insert [-inf,a] and [b,+inf]. Make sure to keep the identity of the original intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Have all nodes in two trees simultaneously. Tree A holds them by key `ai` and tree B holds them by key `bi`.
Insertion and deletion is obviously `O(log n)`.
For requirement 3, print the nodes in B from the smallest to the biggest and stop when `bi` is still smaller then the point. Same, but backwards, in A.

Example:
Given `(1,10), (5,18), (13,20)`, and a point `12`.
The interval(s) in A where `ai` is bigger than `12` is `(13,20)`, and in B the interval(s) that are smaller are `(1,10)`.

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: Gotcha. But what's the complexity of requirement 3 going to be in this case ?

Comment: `O(n)`, it must be. You might be printing the entire tree, so that means you're going over the entire tree. (correlating in the example, think what if the point was `45`).